# Duda con Conversión de OracleDecimal a System.Double

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, programación-funcional

el asunto es el siguiente, resulta que estoy trayendo de un método una variable que viene desde una tabla de una base de datos de Oracle en tipo OracleDecimal cuyo valor es 4.5, el asunto es que cuando trato de Convertir este valor a un System.Double, dicho valor me queda como 45. Resulta que la configuración Regional la tengo en Ingles con simbolo decimal '.' , al cambiar la Configuración Regional al Español de Colombia el simbolo decimal queda en ',' y la conversión funciona muy bien trayendo el 4,5, pero en configuración regional Ingles me  trae es 45. Como hago para solucionar este inconveniente y que al momento de aplicar cualquier configuración regional sea ingles o español el me traiga ese numero decimal en la conversión del System.double. Como este aplicativo que estoy desarrollando va a quedar en varios equipos clientes y algunos clientes tienen la configuración regional en Ingles y otros en español, por eso necesito cuadrar este tema

De antemano muchas gracias,

Comment: Pero... ¿estás cambiando el valor en la base de datos o por programación para presentarlo en la aplicación?

Comment: podrias mostrar lo que hace tu programa para hacer la conversion? a la mayoria de ellos les podes pasar un objeto CultureInfo para evitar este problema

Comment: Supongo que estas usando un Convert.ToDouble(), debes validar que el objeto y si es una cadena, o un string validar que el valor venga con coma (,) no con . y cambiar por el carácter correcto, luego si puedes hacer la conversión.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos por su respuesta, para este problema me ha servido la solución de Miguel Zarate. Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratarla como cadena y con cultura indeterminada
en esta funcion te explico la conversion

```
public decimal TextoaDecimal(string s){
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
// ejemplo string s = "1,14535765" o string s="1.141516";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, clone);

return decimal;
}
```

saludos.